# Infragistics UltraGrid summary updating when grid not visible

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

i'm having some issues with Ultragrid, here is the situation:
(developing c# win-form)
my main form have scrollable tablelayoutpanel, with several UserControls, added dynamically. 
each UserControl contains UltraGrid.
the user can change things on the form, that will cause the data on all grids to be updated.
this update is for all grids, and should cause summary update to the grids.
the problem is that grids that are not visible to the user, doesn't get updated. (not all grids visible but user can scroll to see them)
i've found over the net, that this is not a bug, as it's due to performance
things, that summary values updated only when the grid is visible.
is there a way to force the grid to update summaries, event when it is not visible?

thanks.

Comment: Kindly provide some code which your have tried running.

Comment: I would contact Infragistics support with a sample that demonstrates the issue: https://www.infragistics.com/my-account/submit-support-request/windows-forms

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see the summary, how do you know it's not updated? I would think that getting the SummaryValue.Value would force the summary to be calculated at that point, even if it's not visible on the screen. But I could be wrong.